# Where can I buy some usdt in small amount for testing on mainnet

Tags: go-ethereum

Any where to buy small amount of usdt of mainnet for testing?

Comment: Any exchange like coinbase, binance, etc. If you have ether try kyberswap or other decentralized exchange.

Comment: I checked kyberswap.com but I saw tusd and usdt which one is the one of tether? With contract add 0xdac17...

Comment: It appears to be usdt. At least it has the same logo than tether address in etherscan.